# The SMB Version 1 is disabled on server but the status still shows running

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, smb

I disabled SMB1 on Windows Server 2008 R2 using the command:

```
sc.exe config lanmanworkstation depend= bowser/mrxsmb20/nsi
sc.exe config mrxsmb10 start= disabled
```

When I checked again using the command : `Get-Service mrxsmb10` if SMB1 is disabled, then the Status showed "Running"

Someone please tell me why SMB1 is still running even though I disabled it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this option will **require reboot** to take effect.

Also for SMB version 1 you can make it via registry.

To discover services use:

```
Get-Item HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath}
```

To disable:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters" SMB1 -Type DWORD -Value 0 –Force
```

To enable:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters" SMB1 -Type DWORD -Value 1 –Force
```

Once again. Don't forget for reboot to take effect!

Answer (score 0):

You needed to stop the `mrxsmb10` service and restart the `lanmanworkstation` service to fix SMBv1 without a reboot. Or really, reboot and have the SMBv1 stopped this way. Disabling the service does NOT stop it right away.